# Disabling SSH Timeout When Connecting to/from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssh, timeout, ubuntu-18.04

I used putty on windows to connect ssh to my droplet of Digitaloccean, but ssh session will expire after a short inactivity. What configuration I need to prolong the session timeout?

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 places you need to set configuration for: **TESTED WORKING**

**Client config:**

-Open file /etc/ssh/ssh_config and set directive ServerAliveInterval to a value like 100 for example:

```
# other configs
ServerAliveInterval 100
```

This causes your SSH client to send keep-alive messages every 100 seconds so that the server doesn't drop your connection.

**Server config**

-Open file /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add these configurations at the end of the file to ensure they're not overriden by later lines:

```
# other configs
ClientAliveInterval 600
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveCountMax 10
```

These are conservative settings that will make your SSH Server only disconnect after (600 * 10 = 6000) seconds of user inactivity. Customize these if you need more.

**Restart the ssh server so that changes take effect:**

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Source: http://queirozf.com/entries/disabling-ssh-timeout-when-connecting-to-from-ubuntu

Comment: This question is specific to a Windows client using Putty.  Where does one edit the file  /etc/ssh/ssh_config in this scenario, or is this even a relevant step for Windows/Putty?

Answer (score 7):

To prevent all your clients from timing out you need to edit `/etc/sshd_config` which is the server-side configuration file add these two options:

```
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 720
```

The first one configures the server to send `null packets` to clients every 120 seconds and the second one configures the server to close the connection if the client has been inactive for 720 intervals that are `720*120 = 86400 seconds = 24 hours`

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 the config file is /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Restart with sudo systemctl restart ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot of Windows putty client configuration with TCP KeepAlive enabled:

[image: Screenshot of Windows putty client configuration with TCP KeepAlive enabled]

**Please don't forget to save the session configuration!!!** :-)

Answer (score -3):

CD /etc/
grep -R TMOUT
Comment out all the lines in all the files displayed in above grep output.